# Let $ f(x) $ be the solution of $ \ \int_{0}^{x}e^{(x-t)} f(t) dt=x, \ \ x>0 $.

Tags: definite-integrals

Let $ f(x) $ be the solution of $ \ \int_{0}^{x}e^{(x-t)} f(t) dt=x, \ \ x>0 $. Then $ f(1)= ? $

(a) $-1 $,

(b) $ 0 $,

(c) $ 1 $,

(d) $ 2 $,

**Ans.**  $ \int_{0}^{x}e^{(x-t)}f(t)dt=x $. Differentiating under integral sign , we get

**Any help ?**

Comment: Write it as $\int_0^x e^{-t}f(t){\rm d}t = x e^{-x}$. This is easier to differentiate. In general if both the integrand and the limits depend on $x$ then you can use [Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) to find the derivative.

Comment: can you tell me the answer ?

Comment: Why don't you try to do the work instead! If something is not clear about the derivation then you can ask about that.

Comment: how to solve , i am not sure .

Comment: To derive the integral function, use the fundamental theorem of calculus

Comment: ok , i got it , f(x)=1-x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By differentiation:
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx} \, \int_{0}^{x} e^{x-t} \, f(t) \, dt &= \frac{d}{dx} \, x = 1 \\
\int_{0}^{x} \frac{d}{dx}\left( e^{x-t} \, f(t) \right) \, dt + \frac{d}{dx} \, (x) \, e^{x - x} \, f(x) &= 1 \\
\int_{0}^{x} e^{x-t} \, f(t) \, dt + f(x) &= 1 \\
x + f(x) &= 1 \\
f(x) = 1-x.  
\end{align}

Alternate method by Laplace transform (standard notation):
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}\left\{\int_{0}^{t} e^{t - u} \, f(u) \, du \right\} &= \mathcal{L}\left\{ t \right\} \\
f(s) * \mathcal{L}\left\{ e^{t} \right\} &= \frac{1}{s^2} \\
\frac{f(s)}{s-1} &= \frac{1}{s^2} \\
f(s) &= \frac{1}{s} - \frac{1}{s^2} \\
f(t) &= 1 - t.
\end{align}

Now, since $f(t) = 1- t$ the desired result is evident.

Answer (score 3):

You are differentiating it wrongly.

After differentiating you should get: $$f(x)+\int_0^x e^{x-t}f(t) \ dt =1$$

Comment: So what would be the value of $ f(1) $  ? , is it -1 ?

Comment: The integral is a known laplace transform. It's number 33 in http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/pdf/Laplace_Table.pdf